# Difference UnixNano and MySQL usage

Tags: mysql, time, go

http://golang.org/pkg/time/

I am building a ISO and RFC complaint core for my new Go system. I am using MySQL and am currently figuring out the most optimal setup for the most important base-tables.

I am trying to figure out how to store the date-time in the database. I want to aim at a good balance between the space the saved time in the database will occupy, but also the query-capabilties and the compatibility with UTC and easy timezone conversion that doesn't give annoying conflicts for inserting and retrieving data into/from Go/MySQL.

I know this sounds a bit weird in context to the title of my question. But I see a lot of wrappers, ORM's and such still storing UNIX timestamps (microseconds?). I think it would be good to just always store UTC nano timestamps and just accepting losing the date/time querying functionalities. I don't want to get into problems when running the system with tons of different countries/languages/timezones/currencies/translations/etc. (internationalizations and localizations). I already encountered these problems before with some systems at work and it drove me nuts to the point where eventually tons of fixes had to be applied through the whole codebase to at least some of the conversion back into order. I don't want this to happen in my system. If it means I always have to do some extra coding to keep all stored times in correct UTC+0, I will take that for granted. Based on ISO-8601 and the timezone aberrations and daytime-savings I will determine the output of the date/time.

The story above is opinion based. But my actual question would be what solely is more efficient to choose Go's timestamp as INT stored vs MySQL TIMESTAMP or DATETIME;

1.) What is most optimal considering storage?

2.) What is most optimal considering timezone conventions?

3.) What is most optimal considering speed and MySQL querying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to all these questions is simply storing the timestamp in UTC time with `t.UTC().UnixNano()`, keep in mind that time is int64 so it will always be 8 bytes in the database regardless of precision.

Comment: Would I just do date offset matching based on the integer values ?  I will lose all time functions, but I guess it won't be to hard to bind UnixNano's into the query

Comment: @Allendar if you're using `https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/` it transparently handles it, however it's easy to convert UnixNano() to time, just `t := time.Unix(0, nanoValue)`